# Next.js deployment on Vercel: Unknown file extension ".mts"

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel

The project was always deployed successfully, but at some point it stopped deploying from any branch.

[image: Error]

as you can see on the photo it is absolutely two identical commits and two identical deployments, but at some point it started giving this error

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".mts" for /vercel/path0/scripts/runner.mts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:136:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:182:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:101:20)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:864:28)
    at load (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@commitlint/load/node_modules/ts-node/dist/child/child-loader.js:19:122)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:864:28)
    at Hooks.load (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:447:26)
    at MessagePort.handleMessage (node:internal/modules/esm/worker:196:24)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:786:20) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
```